# Kotlin data class, JsonProperty and RestTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jackson, resttemplate

I hava a Kotlin data class that uses `@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)`, everything works fine, however restTemplate cannot post for object when that annotation is on top of the field and in debugging it shows authorIds is `null`.

```
@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
var authorIds: List<Long>? = null
```

And here is my restTemplate:

```
headers.contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8
val article = getArticleDTO()
val entity = HttpEntity(article, headers)
val response = restTemplate.postForObject(baseUri, entity, ArticleDTO::class.java)
```

If I run the application everything works find from the swagger, `authorIds` are shown for post and in response they are not shown.

I also use `jackson-module-kotlin` and here is my bean:

```
@Bean
fun objectMapper(): ObjectMapper {
    val mapper = ObjectMapper()
    mapper.registerModule(KotlinModule())
    mapper.registerModule(JavaTimeModule())
    return mapper
}
```

Comment: I would guess, when response has to be deserialized - which means reading JSON values - your field is WRITE_ONLY, so it will never be read.

Comment: @Neo the thing is I don't want it to be serialized but want it to be deserialized. I debugged the controller and even in the controller it receives it as null, which shouldn't. Through Postman/Swagger it works fine.